# Problems with exporting a list to Excel

Tags: sharepoint-online, column, export-to-excel

I have modified my view and selected just the columns that i want to show. But when I export the content to excel I can see more columns. (In my nomal view I am not seeing them, just when I export it to excel) Does anyone know how to avoid this? I just want my selected columns in my excel .. 
Oh! Another interesting issue is that not all the columns that are exported to excel are avialable to check or uncheck in the modify view tab, some of them not ever "exist".

How can I unlock this columns from showing in my exported Excel?

Thank you!